# How to convert array of events into HH:mm format

Tags: reactjs, datetime, events, momentjs, converters

I have an array with start and end called blockedTime. How can I convert these elements into `HH:mm` format? I have also seen how people use momentjs library, but whenever I tried to use it I didn't get the answer I wanted

```
   const BlockedTime = [
    {
        start: "2021-04-19T09:30:00.0",
        end: "2021-04-19T10:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        start: "2021-04-19T14:00:00.0",
        end: "2021-04-19T14:30:00.0"
    },
    {
        start: "2021-04-19T16:00:00.0",
        end: "2021-04-19T16:30:00.0"
    }

]
```

Comment: To loop each object you can use `blockedTime.map`. Then using the moment library you can convert string to date like `start = moment(new Date(item.start))`. And finally format it with `start.format('HH:mm')`. What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each item of the array and you can use `format function` from the moment and pass `HH:mm`. The rough code will look something like below.

```
import moment from "moment";
let time_data =  [ { start: "2021-04-19T09:30:00.0", end: "2021-04-19T10:00:00.0" },
{ start: "2021-04-19T14:00:00.0", end: "2021-04-19T14:30:00.0" }, 
{ start: "2021-04-19T16:00:00.0", end: "2021-04-19T16:30:00.0" }];

time_data = time_data.map(item=>({start_time : moment(item.start).format("HH:mm"),end_time : moment(item.end).format("HH:mm")}));
console.log(time_data)
```